# Define member variable as pointer or object

Tags: c++

Say I have two classes:

"A.h"

```
#include "B.h"

class A
{
public:
    unique_ptr<B> b; //store as pointer
    B b; //store as object

    A() : b(new B())
    {

    }
};
```

"B.h"

```
class B
{
public:
    //huge class

    void foo() {};
};
```

And I want to use A in main:
"main.cpp"

```
#include "A.h"
int main()
{
    unique_ptr<A> a(new A());
    a->b->foo();
    a->b.foo();
}
```

**Question 1:** Would I have any performance gains when storing and using B as a pointer instead of an object inside of A?
**Question 2:** Say I wouldn't have #included B in "A.h" but instead I would have forward declared B:

```
class B;
```

Then, inside main I could't call a->b->foo(), since B isn't included anywhere. What would be better design, including "B.h" in "A.h" or including it in "main.cpp" where I'm actually using the function? Including it in "A.h" would break the rule of forward declaring everything that isn't actually used, but including it in "main.cpp" is awful for the programmer that is using the classes. I really have complex classes where I want to avoid any #include that is possible, to avoid chaos later.

Comment: Unless you need to replace `b` with a different object (i.e. change what it points to) then composition may be preferred here. Hard to say without knowing more details of the design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes, an `A` object would be smaller since it simply has a pointer to a `B` rather than carrying around a copy of a `B`

2) You can forward declare `B` in `A`, you just need to `#include "B.h"` in your `main.cpp`. In reality (as in, large programs), you would simply be including this header in the actual file that uses the header, not `main` itself. Include it where you use it, don't be afraid to include things. Obviously keep it to the minimum number of headers that are needed, but don't get complicated just to avoid includes.

Comment: Thank you!
1) But therefore, b must be dereferenced each time I access it. Doesn't this impact on performance?